# API response is not showing in Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, https, http-post

I'm using Powershell v4.

I am calling a POST API and want to see the response when I run `Invoke-RestMethod` but it just shows a new line.

[image]

How can I output the response from the API to the console?  I have tried running it in a script with `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`, but nothing appears on the console screen.

**PowerShell script:**

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://localhost:8081/myAPI -Body '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' -ContentType application/json -Method POST 
Write-Host $Response
```

I can see the response when I `curl` the API but cannot see it in my PowerShell script which I need to use.

**CURL**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' https://localhost:8081/myAPI
```

It looks like its not even hitting the API as nothing appears in the API logs when triggering from Powershell.  Not sure how to resolve that if that is the problem.

Comment: You should wrap your statement in a try catch block and see what Powershell is actually getting. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771424/how-to-get-powershell-invoke-restmethod-to-return-body-of-http-500-code-response

Answer (score 1):

Your command has a syntax error.  Your contenttype is not in proper format.

You have:

```
-ContentType application/json
```

Change it to:

```
-ContentType "application/json"
```