# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Internal Server Error

Tags: powershell

When I run this (parameters and body that worked from Postman):

```
$Url = "http://${IPADDR}:8080/api/v1/topology/query"

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Access-Token', 'token')
$headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
$headers.Add('Accept', 'application/json')

$json = 
'{
"includes":[{"ids":["264690t5te74hy4y"],"observationName":"page_life_expectancy"}],
"startTime":1528718400000,
"endTime":1528768800000,
"granularity":3600000,
"numberOfValue":1,
"retrievalType":"RAW"
}'

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $json

$ple = $response | select -ExpandProperty data | select max
```

in Powershell ISE, I get this:

> An error occurred while calling REST method at: http://${IPADDR}:8080/api/v1/topology/query. Error: The remote server returned an 
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error.. Response body: Apache Tomcat/7.0.82 - Error report

Any expert in Powershell, JSON, and REST API that can help me with this issue?

Comment: Why are you converting your json?  It serves no purpose.

Comment: Nobody can help you with an "500 Internal Server Error". Use a different tool (such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) and get the request to work manually. Once you have something that definitely works, you can easily re-create that in Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

From PowerShell since you serialize the content to JSON, specify -ContentType "application/json".  Also, if you think the content might contain unicode strings, include the -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8".

Answer (score 1):

The content of the Body parameter of Invoke-RestMethod should be an object serialized in JSon. In your example, you have 3 levels of serialization.

You should remove 2 levels of serialization:

```
$jsonBody = '{
"includes":[{"ids": 
    ["264690t5te74hy4y"],"observationName":"page_life_expectancy"}],
    "startTime":1528718400000,
    "endTime":1528768800000,
    "granularity":3600000,
    "numberOfValue":1,
   "retrievalType":"RAW"
}'

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody
```

But it's not guaranteed that the error 500 disappear.

You may have more details about the error with the Exception content. You can try that:

```
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    if (Get-Member -InputObject $_.Exception -Name 'Response') {
        try {
            $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
            $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
            $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
        } catch {
            Throw "An error occurred while calling REST method at: $url. Error: $errorMessage. Cannot get more information."
        }
    }
    Throw "An error occurred while calling REST method at: $url. Error: $errorMessage. Response body: $responseBody"
}
```

Error handling from post: [How to get Powershell Invoke-Restmethod to return body of http 500 code response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771424/how-to-get-powershell-invoke-restmethod-to-return-body-of-http-500-code-response)

Comment: Thank you Julien for your helpful insight! I changed my code up like yours, and the  string $jsonbody is actually the body that worked from postman, However, i still get  this error: 

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At line:26 char:5
+     Throw $_.Exception
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you tried the **try {} catch {}** part to get more information about the error ?
You should have an output like that:
`StatusCode: 500`, `StatusDescription: xxx`

Comment: I did run your try{} catch{} lines. I am not sure why it didn't return an output like "StatusCode"... any ideas?

Comment: The StatusCode: and StatusDescription: should appear before the Error. Could you try to remove the line `Throw $_.Exception` to better view the output ?

Comment: oh yes my bad. It says StatusCode: 500
StatusDescription: Internal Server Error

Comment: I updated the _try {} catch {}_ block in my answer. Can you try with this new version ?

Comment: i just did, and it now says PS C:\Windows\system32>     if (Get-Member -InputObject $_.Exception -Name 'Response') {
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

Comment: i know that your code is not missing a } though. so im not sure why it would give such problems

Comment: here, im about to edit my question! hopefully that will give you a better view

Comment: OK, so now you get the full message from the server and there is nothing in it that can help to resolve your problem :-/ You may try to contact the owner of the server and ask for server logs.

Comment: I'm facing this issue now. What I have concluded is the Invoke-RestMethod has some limit of the body to post and cuts it off (instead of saying "hey, this is too big"). Because the same exact JSON works in Postman but in PowerShell the server complains that the JSON is missing parts at the end.