# Create reviewers for environments in github repository

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, github-api, environment, github-api-v3

The below powershell works and helps create environment `test_mont` under repo `variables`

```
# Define the owner, repository, environment, token, and reviewer variables
$owner = "knowyrtech" # The name of the owner of the repository
$repo = "variables" # The name of the repository
$envName = "test_mont" # The name of the environment
$token = "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" # The authentication token for accessing the GitHub API

$uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/environments/$envName"
$header = @{"Authorization" = "token $token"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Header $header -ContentType $contentType -Uri $uri
```

Next, Below powershell adds reviewers into the created environment which fails.

```
# Define the owner, repository, environment, token, and reviewer variables
$owner = "knowyrtech" # The name of the owner of the repository
$repo = "variables" # The name of the repository
$envName = "test_mont" # The name of the environment
$token = "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" # The authentication token for accessing the GitHub API

# Define the required reviewers (GitHub usernames) you want to add
$requiredReviewers = @("knowyrtech")
#$requiredReviewers = @("mybank/are-devops")

# Convert the list of reviewers to JSON format
$reviewersJson = $requiredReviewers | ForEach-Object {
    @{
        reviewer = $_
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json


# GitHub API URL for updating environment protection rules
$uri = https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/environments/$envName/reviewers

# Set headers with the authentication token
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "token $token"
    "Accept" = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}

# Send a POST request to add the required reviewers to the environment
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body $reviewersJson -ContentType "application/json" 

# Check the response
if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Required reviewers added to the environment."
} else {
    Write-Host "Failed to add required reviewers."
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":https://docs.github.com/rest}
At line:26 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Failed to add required reviewers.
```

I also tried:

```
# Convert the list of reviewers to JSON format

$reviewersJson = $requiredReviewers | ForEach-Object {
    @{
        "reviewers" = [
            @{
                "type" = "User"
                "id" = $_
            }
        ]
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

But getting an error:

```
At line:12 char:24 + "reviewers" = [ + ~ Missing type name after '['. At line:16 char:14 + } + ~ Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal. At line:10 char:54 + $reviewersJson = $requiredReviewers | ForEach-Object { + ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

Finally, I tried replacing `"reviewers" = [` with `"reviewers" : [` but that too did not work.

I also tried changing the uri to `$uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/environments/$envName/protection-rules"`

The environment is visible and accessible as below:

https://api.github.com/repos/knowyrtech/variables/environments/test_mont

[image]

Kindly suggest adding multiple reviewers to the environment using `API` calls.

Update: tried solutions by @050 but getting a series of errors:

```
1. Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Invalid request.\n\nInvalid property /reviewers/0/id: `\"knowyrtech\"` is not of type 
`integer`.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/deployments/environments#create-or-update-an-environment"}
At line:37 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Header $header -Body $revi ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
Failed to add required reviewers.

2. Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Invalid request.\n\nInvalid property /reviewers: `{\"id\"=>111655092, \"type\"=>\"User\"}` is not of type 
`array`.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/deployments/environments#create-or-update-an-environment"}
At line:36 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Header $header -Body $revi ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

3. Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"} At line:33 char:13 + $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers ... +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand Failed to add required reviewers
```

Comment: Try this `$reviewersJson = @{reviewers = @(@{type="user";id="1"},@{type="user";id="2"})}`  . Also, `id` does appear to need to be your userid not username so it'll need to be a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the proper format you need to do something like this:

```
# adding multiple users
# $requiredReviewers = @{reviewers = @(@{type="User";id=111655092},@{type="User";id=123456})}

#single user
$requiredReviewers = @{reviewers = @(@{type="User";id=111655092})}

# to add a team: 'type=User' needs to be 'type=Team' and you need to 
# use the teamid
#{type="Team";id=123456}

# Convert the list of reviewers to JSON format
$reviewersJson =  ConvertTo-Json $requiredReviewers
```

The `id` is your user id so it'll be a number. I put the user id for the username that you have listed in your example. You can get the user id by replacing "usernamehere" with your username.
https://api.github.com/users/usernamehere

There is also a restriction on the number of users/teams you can add **"You can list up to six users or teams as reviewers"**([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/environments?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-an-environment)).

Also the url needs to be in quotes and was wrong:

`$uri = https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/environments/$envName/reviewers`

Remove "**/reviewers**" at the end of the url and add quotes:

`$uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/environments/$envName"`

After making those changes I was able to successfully run the script.

****Adding Teams****

It's essentially the same as adding a user, except you change `type="User"` to `type="Team"`. You will also need to obtain the teamid. You can do this via api call. Bellow will output your teamid. Your token will have to have correct permissions. ([Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-team-by-name))

```
$headers = @{Authorization = "token yourtoken"}
# org name
$myorg = "mybank"
# team name
$team = "are-devops"

$content = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -URI https://api.github.com/orgs/$myorg/teams/$team
$items = $content.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 

Write-Output $items.id
```

Alternatively, you could just go to your team page right click the avatar image and copy the address. The team id will be in the link.

`https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/t/team-id-is-here?s=116&v=4`

Comment: Answer works for adding users but Adding teams to reviewers is failing like `mybank\knowyrtech` @kconsiglio

Comment: `type="User"` would need to change to `type="Team"`, along with the corresponding team id.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a little error in the JSON's syntax. Each object of the JSON must be between semicolons. Try this:

```
$reviewersJson = $requiredReviewers | ForEach-Object {
    @{
        "reviewers" = 
            @{
                "type" = "User";
                "id" = $_
            }
        
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: i get the following error `Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
At line:33 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method PUT -Headers $headers ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
Failed to add required reviewers.
.`

Comment: i updated with original post as I was getting several errors.

Comment: The original post has all relevant data so could you run the  solution powershel in ISE to make sure it is working alright? @050

Comment: I'm not on my machine for the moment, so I can't help you with that. However, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049501/invoke-webrequest-400-bad-request-detailed-message) to get more insight of the errors you're getting.

Comment: i tried several changes and posted respective error messages post your suggestions in the original post. could you check by running whichever day  you get back to your system please?

Comment: @kconsiglio i have a organization team where we have users + teams with org name like `mybank\knowyrtech`. Can you also suggest how can I add teams to reviewers ?